# Material Design Lite - Tool Tip positioning

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

When using MDL tooltips (https://getmdl.io/components/#tooltips-section) the tooltip appears just below the `<div>` that it is linked to.

I would like to have the tooltip appear to the right of the element it referencing, instead of underneath.

So far I have attempted editing my styles.css like so unsuccessfully
`.mdl-tooltip {
right: 50px;
}`

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `mdl-tooltip--right` class to your `tooltip`:

```html
<div id="tt1">add</div>
<div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--right" data-mdl-for="tt1">
Follow
</div>
```

Comment: This works as does other styles `mdl-tooltip--top`.
What tripped me up is that they arent styles they are done in javascript so if you change them you'll need to do `componentHandler.upgradeDom()`